# Listing-Unlisting error while performing loop calculations in R

Tags: r, list

While perform an iterative calculation of 4 steps, I get an error saying

> Error in eps[[i]] = rnorm(100, 0, sigma) : 
>     more elements supplied than there are to replace

The code is:

```
f <- list()
residual <- list()
eps <- list()
err <-list()
y<- list()



for(i in 1:4){
eps[[i]]=rnorm(100,0,sigma)
eps<-t(sapply(eps, unlist))
y[[i]]= b0 + b1*x1  + b2*x2  + eps
y<-t(sapply(y, unlist))
residual[[i]]= e*y
f[[i]]=e*eps
err[[i]]=eps
}
```

Note that `b0,b1,b2,sigma` are constants, `x1,x2` are each a vector of order 100 and `e` is a square matrix of order 100.

Comment: Please share defined value of `sigma`.

Comment: @MKR yes, `sigma=1.4`

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are trying to do. Why store it in `eps` and then unlist??

Comment: `replicate(4,rnorm(100,0,1))+ b0 + b1*x1  + b2*x2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot add a list to a vector. I have assumed the lists were meant to be indexed with i.
2. No need to unlist when it is already vectors.

Does this do what you meant?

```
f <- list()
residual <- list()
eps <- list()
err <-list()
y<- list()
sigma=1.4
b0 <- 17 
b1 <- 0.5 
b2 <- 0.037
x1 = 1:100
x2=101:200
e = matrix(nrow = 100, ncol = 100, data = 1:10000)
for(i in 1:4){
  eps[[i]]=rnorm(100,0,sigma)
  #eps<-t(sapply(eps, unlist))
  y[[i]]= b0 + b1*x1  + b2*x2  + eps[[i]]
  #y<-t(sapply(y, unlist))
  residual[[i]]= e*y[[i]]
  f[[i]]=e*eps[[i]]
  err[[i]]=eps[[i]]
}
```

Comment: thanks, but `e` is a square matrix of order 100, as I have stated, and yes, when I tried your code, I get the same error as I stated

Comment: I have changed e to a matrix, sorry about that. This works perfectly well in R 3.4.3. Try it in a clean session and update variables as needed. Does it work as you intended?

Comment: again tried, but I get the error-`Error in b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + eps[[i]] : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: Did you paste it to a clean session? When I try it on codingground (http://www.compileonline.com/execute_r_online.php) it works fine?

Comment: yes, I tried it in a new session, but the same error

Comment: sorry and thanks, works fine now. the mistake was that i used list () while defining eps inside the loop.

Comment: Glad to hear :-) Don’t forget to mark as correct answer if it answers your question

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the line

```
eps[[i]]=rnorm(100,0,1)
```

as

```
eps[[i]]=list(rnorm(100,0,1))
```

Also, corresponding changes will be as:

```
b0 <- 17
b1 <- 0.5
b2 <- 0.037
for(i in 1:4){
  eps[[i]]=list(rnorm(100,0,1))
  #eps<-t(sapply(eps, unlist))
  y[[i]]= b0 + b1*x1  + b2*x2 + as.data.frame(eps[[i]])
  y<-t(sapply(y, unlist))
  residual[[i]]= e*as.data.frame(y[[i]])
  f[[i]]=e*as.data.frame(eps[[i]])
  err[[i]]=eps[[i]]
}
```

Comment: tried, but I get the error `Error in b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + eps : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: @vidyarthi Expected. Please share value of all constants.

Comment: the constants are `b0 <- 17 b1 <- 0.5 b2 <- 0.037`